# Constructing the Redux state

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux and having a bit of trouble with it, so what I've done so far might very well be wrong, but bear with me. Overall, I want a very simple redux state for my app, with only two keys, "user" and "landing". The way I have everything set up is defaulting the state to "user: {user: null}", and "landing: {landing: true}". I'm wondering why it's duplicated like that, and it's not just "user: null" and "landing: true"?

My reducers:

```
const initialUserState = {
    user: null
};
const initialUiState = {
    landing: true
};

export function userReducer(state, action){
    if (typeof state === "undefined"){
        return initialUserState;
    }
    switch(action.type){
        case SIGN_IN: 
            return {...state, user: action.userName};
        case SIGN_OUT: 
            return {...state, user: null};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export function uiReducer(state, action){
    if (typeof state === "undefined"){
        return initialUiState;
    }
    switch(action.type){
        case LANDING: 
            return {...state, landing: true};
        case NOT_LANDING: 
            return {...state, landing: false};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the combination of the reducers:

```
import {userReducer, uiReducer} from "./reducers";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer, 
    landing: uiReducer
});
```

Again, I'm hoping to see just "user: null" and "landing: true", but I'm console logging out the state in a component that's wrapped in connect and I'm seeing "user: {user: null}" and "landing: {landing: true}".

Answer (score 0):

The first hierarchy level in the state is defined by the name of the reducers in the call to `combineReducers`. This is necessary to separate the sub-state that each single reducer is responsible for. The structure of the state inside the first hierarchy level is then completely defined by the corresponding reducers.

In your case, if you really want to manage only a single value, you could define your reducers as follows:

```
const initialUserState = null;

export function userReducer(state, action){
  if (typeof state === "undefined"){
    return initialUserState;
  }
  switch(action.type){
    case SIGN_IN: 
        return action.userName;
    case SIGN_OUT: 
        return null;
    default: 
        return state;
  }
}
```

And similarly for the `uiReducer`. 
But this would be rather uncommon and won't scale well if you need to add further attributes in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Huge help. I went ahead and initialized the "user" portion of state to an object with "auth" and "userName" keys, changed the "landing" portion to "page" and gave it an object with a key of "landing"